# Flex 3 - What Component to extend for drawing application

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I wonder which component to extend in Flex 3 in order to make a drawing stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs at http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=Drawing_Vector_Graphics_1.html#153021

> You can draw with ActionScript on any
>   **Shape**, **Sprite**, or **MovieClip** instance,
>   using the graphics property defined in
>   each of those classes.

Comment: Yes i know that but i wonder if i should extend Canvas or other flex component

Comment: There is no special need to extend Canvas or any other UIComponent subclass. You can extend one of the classes listed above or Canvas or any other UIComponent if you want.